# how to display full image taken from camera in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying display a whole image taken by the camera using an img tag with a width of 600 and a height of 800 pixels. but for some reason after taking a photo it is cut once displayed. how can i fit the photo inside the 600x800pixel img element?

here's my code for controllers.js:

```
.controller('idValidationCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$cordovaCamera','$cordovaFile', function ($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaCamera,$cordovaFile) {
 $scope.addImage = function()
{
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

//Callback function when the picture has been successfully taken
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {                
    // Get image handle
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

    // Unhide image elements
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = imageData;
}

//Callback function when the picture has not been successfully taken
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed to load picture because: ' + message);
}

}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added this instead to the  tag in html: style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain'